How to configure clang-format to place ) and } on a new line?
I’m trying to configure clang-format to break after each function parameter and place ) and } on separate lines for (member) function declarations and calls, like this:
void draw(
    const geometry::rect &source,
    const geometry::rect &destination,
    const double angle = 0.0,
    flip flip = flip::none,
    const uint8_t alpha = 255
) const noexcept;

Or this
  lua.new_usertype<audio::soundmanager>(
      "SoundManager",
      "play", &audio::soundmanager::play,
      "stop", &audio::soundmanager::stop
  );

I don't want the code to be formatted like this:
  lua.new_usertype<audio::soundmanager>(
      "SoundManager",
      "play", &audio::soundmanager::play,
      "stop", &audio::soundmanager::stop);

Here is the .clang-format file I have so far:
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 2
TabWidth: 2
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
ColumnLimit: 0
AccessModifierOffset: -2
FixNamespaceComments: false


This question is similar to: clang-format closing bracket on a new line. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@STerliakov Indeed, the linked Q&A solves it for normal parentheses. Do you know how to do it for braces? Maybe Rodrigo should better specialize on braces here?

@Rodrigo What do you think about AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent? Would you concentrate on closing braces in this question then?

@Wolf As currently written, this is an exact dupe except for } mention in the title. I don't see any case in clang-format docs where closing brace is placed on the same line as preceding statement besides trivial (empty) block. If this question asks about braces, it needs clear example of observed and desired behaviour - I can't deduce them from the description alone.

The const noexcept on the closing parenthesis let me conclude that you are in fact showing us a decontextualized method declaration here. I tried to build a test file to cover interesting use cases.
Input test.cpp:
int fun(int const *a, const int &b,
    const int c, const int d, const int e) noexcept;

class Foo {

  public:

    int bar(
        int const *a,
        int const &b,
        const int some_c, int const some_d, const int some_e
    ) const noexcept {
        const int f = fun(a, b, some_c, some_d, some_e);
        return scale *f;
    }

private:

    const int scale = 10;

};


int fun(
const int *a, const int &b, const int c, const int d, const int e) noexcept {

    return *a + b + (c-d)*e;
}

I based .custom-style file on Chromium and adjusted several config values:
.custom-style:
---
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
Language: Cpp
IndentWidth: 4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Right
# not shown in original question:
AccessModifierOffset: -2
QualifierAlignment: Left
...

I run the command
$> clang-format --style=file:.custom-style` test.cpp > test-s.cpp

Output (test-s.cpp):
int fun(
    const int *a,
    const int &b,
    const int c,
    const int d,
    const int e
) noexcept;

class Foo {
  public:
    int bar(
        const int *a,
        const int &b,
        const int some_c,
        const int some_d,
        const int some_e
    ) const noexcept {
        const int f = fun(a, b, some_c, some_d, some_e);
        return scale * f;
    }

  private:
    const int scale = 10;
};

int fun(
    const int *a,
    const int &b,
    const int c,
    const int d,
    const int e
) noexcept {
    return *a + b + (c - d) * e;
}

Finally, it should be noted that parameters are normally only wrapped if they would otherwise exceed one line. It may still be possible to achieve this by adjusting one or more of the Penalty* values.

How to avoid it to add // namespace framework on each end of namespace?

@Rodrigo To avoid namespace end comments, set FixNamespaceComments: False. (False and false seem to be equivalent.)
